# How can I take a string input like this?

Tags: c++

If I have a string containing unknown number of words, and I have to scan it in multiple strings in C++. How can I do it?

```
For eg: 
"I am a boy". I want, each of these individual words to be in a string. 
"My name is John Lui". Each of these as well.
```

One way that I could think of was to use, `getline` in c++ and then parse through the entire string until a  character is found and store in seperate strings. I want to know is there a better method? Thanks!

Also, I want to know, that when using a `delimiter` in `getline` command, getline basically scans the input strings till the point delimiter is not found and puts that part of a string into a new string. However, I want to know, if the delimiter is not present at all, then what happens? Does it throw an exception or it takes input the whole string till the newline character? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

However you could use ***std::getline***

> Which uses a string instead of a char array. It's easier to use string
>   since they know their sizes, they auto grow etc. and you don't have to
>   worry about the null terminating character and so on. Also it is
>   possible to convert a char array to a string by using the appropriate
>   string contructor.

You can do it by [stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/str/):

```
// stringstream::str
#include <string>       // std::string
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <sstream>      // std::stringstream, std::stringbuf

using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    std::string str;
    getline( std::cin, str );
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss<<str;
    std::string s;
    while(ss>>s)
    {
        std::cout << s << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input: `I am a boy`

Output:

```
I
am
a
boy
```

If you think that, you want each word to store in a `vector`, you can do it like:

```
// stringstream::str
#include <string>       // std::string
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <sstream>      // std::stringstream, std::stringbuf
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    vector <string> V;
    V.clear();
    std::string str;
    getline( std::cin, str );
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss<<str;
    std::string s,s1;
    while(ss>>s)
    {
        V.push_back(s);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But this will take the entire string as input into one variable. I want each and every word into a separate string variable.

Comment: @hans `while(cin >> word) { ... }` then. Read a book about the basics please!

Comment: @hans Now you can see the answer.

Comment: Simply `std::istringstream ss(str);` would work fine as well.